# How to inherit a record from other record in Delphi (like in C++)?

Tags: delphi

I want solutions for RAD Studio 10.2 Berlin, same like in C++.

1. Inherit a record from another record (see following C++ example):

   ```cpp
   typedef struct A
   {
     virtual int ChangeName(const char* Name) = 0;
   } A;

   struct B : public A
   {
     virtual int ChangeValue(const char* Value) = 0;
   };
   ```
2. How are pure virtual functions implemented in Delphi?

Answer (score 3):

Record inheritance is not supported in the Delphi language.

The closest equivalent to a C++ pure virtual function in Delphi is an abstract virtual method. But there are no virtual methods in Delphi records because record inheritance is not supported in the Delphi language.

You can learn all this and more from the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Records_.28advanced.29). Some key excerpts:

> - Records do not support inheritance.
>
> ...
>
> - Virtual methods (those specified with the **virtual**, **dynamic**, and **message** keywords) cannot be used in record types.

Comment: If you absolutely need to simulate C++-like record inheritance in Delphi, you will have to implement the vtable handling by hand, not unlike handling COM interface inheritance in C (which also doesn't support struct inheritance or virtual methods in structs).

Comment: ok,thanks for answer. Can we write Obect instead of record and used virtual methods in it just like  `A = object  function xyz : integer ;virtual;abstract ;end;   `

Comment: Turbo Pascal object has been deprecated for many years. I don't know what the state of the feature is in your version of Delphi. I know there have been bugs in some versions. I don't even know what version you use because there is no 10.2 Berlin. I would never use object in a modern delphi. What problem are you trying to solve? Also, I think I answered the question that you asked.